# how to push data from azure iot to unity 3D

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-iot-hub

I am working on unity and I need a small help. I am trying to push azure iot data to unity 3D. Can anyone tell how can it be done? I have searched on the internet and has not found a reliable information. Please help me with this.

Comment: have a look at the Azure Functions, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview

Comment: Hello Roman Kiss, I have gone through those documents but I was not able to find anything that is related to unity in there. Thank you for the help. If there anything else please provide the information.

Comment: Can you call the Unit 3D using a REST API?

Answer (score 1):

If you build the unity 3D project for Universal Windows Platform as C# project,you can install Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client package, and then use DeviceClient to [receive Cloud-to-Device message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d#receive-messages-in-the-device-app).
Of cause, you can use other azure iot hub SDKs if you did not use C#. Currently, [Auzre IoT Hub SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-device-sdks) support .Net, C, Java, Node.js, Python and iOS.

In addition, as Roman Kiss mentioned in above comment, Azure Function is another option.You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/AzureFunctionsDemo).

[image]